# Retrieving an array through CComPtr<IDispatch> Invoke

Tags: javascript, c++, com, atl

I'm invoking a Javascript function from C++ using CComPtr Invoke(). As long as I return a single element from the Javascript function, I can get extract it from the C++ side using the ComVariant object, whose type is set according to the data type of the returned variable. The problem is that when I try to transfer a whole array from Javascript, the CComVariant object type is set to VT_DISPATCH, not VT_ARRAY. Can anyone please guide me how to retrieve the array elements? I'd be thankful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a JavaScript array() to an ATL/COM array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014711/how-can-i-convert-a-javascript-array-to-an-atl-com-array)

Comment: You're right. Sorry I missed that one.

Comment: Sorry may I know the detail to return a single element from the Javascript function as you said? thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
HRESULT DoSomethingWithAJavaScriptArray(VARIANT v)
{
    if (V_VT(&v) != VT_DISPATCH)
        return E_UNEXPECTED;

    _variant_t out; // need comutil.h

   // get the enumeration method see [Reserved DISPIDs][1]
    HRESULT hr = V_DISPATCH(&v)->Invoke(DISPID_NEWENUM, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, &out, NULL, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    if (V_VT(&out) != VT_UNKNOWN)
        return E_UNEXPECTED;

    // get the IEnumVariant from the interface
    CComPtr<IEnumVARIANT> pEnum;
    hr = V_UNKNOWN(&out)->QueryInterface(IID_IEnumVARIANT, (void**)&pEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // do a foreach
    ULONG fetched = 0;
    do 
    {
        _variant_t element;
        hr = pEnum->Next(1, &element, &fetched);
        if ((FAILED(hr)) || (fetched == 0))
            return S_OK;

        // do something with the VARIANT here
            ...
    }
    while(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: @AlexeySubbota - What doesn't work? Provide more information or post another question.

Comment: Your solution obviously. Array doesn't have DISPID_NEWENUM

Comment: @AlexeySubbota - If I posted that, it worked for me. Post another question with a reproducing code